# Match two tables and return the result table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following two tables in sql server.

Table : 1

```
No    Items
1     70
2     72
3     74
```

Table : 2

```
   Name     Type    date
   abc      70      12/12/2013 01:10
   xyz      70      12/12/2013 10:10
   bcd      74      10/12/2013 08:10 
   efg      74      10/12/2013 09:10
   jkl      70      01/01/2012 23:10
```

Now i want following result:

Result :

```
Chk   Name  Type   Date
1     xyz   70     12/12/2013 10:10
1     efg   74     10:12/2013 09:10
0     abc   70     12/12/2013 01:10
0     bcd   74     10/10/2013 08:10
0     jkl   70     01/01/2012 23:10
```

I want latest entries of each type from table: 1 on the top with chk = 1 in table : 2 in the result table.

Now i want to write sql query to find out above result. Can anyone help me to write sql query for the same?

Comment: There is not enough information to determine what you want.

Comment: To expand on what Charles Bretana is saying:  Why is name "efg" repeated twice in the result set, once with Chk = 1 and once with Chk = 0?  Why is there a date in the result set that does not exist in the initial data table?  Did you leave out "bcd" from initial data table based on your business logic, or is it a typo?  Please explain clearly the logic or correct your expected result set.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
SELECT t1.No AS Chk, t2.Name, t2.Type, t2.date AS [Date] 
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Items = t2.Type 
GROUP BY t1.No, t2.Name, t2.Type, t2.date
ORDER BY t1.No DESC
```

(without actually typing this myself in Mgmt Studio so could be somewhat 'off')

Comment: This won't run because your `GROUP BY` doesn't contain the other columns in your `SELECT` or the other columns in your `SELECT` are not aggregates.

Comment: yes, SO's SQL error handling is notoriously bad :-P (that or my from-the-top-of-my-head knowledge of SQL)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the `chk` column, you want to see if there is a match between the tables.  A good way to do this is using a `left outer join` along with some `case` logic:

```
select (case when t1.no is NULL then 0 else 1 end) as Chk,
       t2.name, t2.type, t2.date
from table2 t2 left outer join
     table1 t1
     on t1.type = t2.items
order by 1, date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
WITH    Tbl
      AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T1.Items ORDER BY date Desc) Row
           FROM     Table1 T1
                    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Items = T2.Type
         )
SELECT  CASE Row
          WHEN 1 THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END chk ,
        Name ,
        Type ,
        Date
FROM    Tbl
```